# Can I have different private config files in different git branches?

Tags: git, branch, configuration-files

We're developing a product and we use Git as our SCM. Each minor version of the product lives in its separate branch. As a developer, I have my own set of databases, one for each minor version. I also have a private configuration file, which is ignored by Git, and it specifies which database to use. But because it is ignored by Git, it stays the same no matter what branch I'm currently on. That's no good, because if the config file says to use database db_1_2 (which is intended for branch 1.2), switching to branch 1.3 leaves the config file still pointing to database db_1_2.

I currently have a piece of code read and parse the branch identifier in an effort to set the correct database, but it is error prone, because the Git identifier comes in many flavors, most of which are rather hard/impossible to resolve the correct branch name from.

I can ask the product itself, but not all of the older versions have a static getVersion() method.

So my question is this: Is there any good and clean way to have a private config file somehow belong to a branch, but not make it to the final product when pushed to the remote/central repo?

Comment: Good question. My approach would be to parse the output of `git branch`, but that's probably what you're doing already.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. Works great when "git name-rev --name-only HEAD" yields something like "1.2", but it all goes down the drain when checking out a certain commit, or bisecting.

Comment: Have you considered using a submodule?

Comment: melee: No. In fact, I didn't even know about the concept until now. Tried to read a little bit about it, but how would you use it in this case?

Comment: Where you find problems with detecting Git branch?

Answer (score 2):

Why is the database version in an ignored config file when the database is so integrally related to the branch?  You are asking for a way to determine the database from the branch but the whole job of a branch is to provide code state specific to a branch and consistent with everything else in the branch.  Move the database identifier out of the config file into something that is not ignored.

Comment: That has already been done, but not in older versions of the product. So when I need to checkout an older version to see what all the fuss from the customer is about, the codebase doesn't give me any hints as to what version it is.

Comment: If it is old code and your codebase isn't clear about what goes with what, then you need to fix that problem!  Perhaps start by tagging stuff so you have a consistent configuration - be it git managed source or databases or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a series of configuration files named after your git branches?  Then you can do something like this when you chance branches:

```
ln -s configs/$(git symbolic-ref HEAD|cut -f3 -d/) myconfig.conf
```

Alternatively, instead of running:

```
git co -b branchname
```

Make a `switchbranch` script does something like:

```
git co -b $1
ln -s configs/$1 myconfig.conf
```

And it all becomes automatic.  You could could even get fancy and create a template configuration file if you switch to a branch for which there is not an existing configuration.

Comment: Looks interesting, but will it handle bisecting, for instance?

Comment: Probably not...or more accurately, not without help.  If you use `git bisect run ...` to handle things then you can probably be the necessary logic in the script.  I'm not familiar with how `git bisect` operates in the context of multiple branches, so I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score -1):

You can have changeable (automatically) config, reflecting branch-changes, if it will be versioned as template and, using idea from [this my post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/142001/36934), you'll add keywords into the branch-dependent part of template and filters for processing these keywords. Branch for any changeset may be

`git branch | grep "*"`

`git status | grep 'On branch'`

`git symbolic-ref -q HEAD` (?)

`git branch | sed --quiet 's/* \(.*\)/\1/p'`

Can't see how to avoid side-effects on pushing